# HTML5/Flash audio recorder library

Tags: html, flash, audio

I need a front-end solution to record audio, but as users do not always use the most modern browsers, flash fall back is necessary. I am looking for an auto-fallback library (such as html5/flash player) to let users record their voices online.

I searched around Google but can't find a satisfying one. Any recommendation?

Thank you so much

Comment: I found Twilio cloud service might be a solution, anything else?

Answer (score 2):

[**Audior**](http://audior.ec) is a flash based solution that can record raw audio from your mic, convert it to **mp3**, give you the mp3 file or upload it to the web server. It keeps the audio in RAM until it's uploaded or saved on your computer so it's not suitable for long recordings where you will loose the data if your browser crashes.

[**FLVAR**](http://flvar.com) is a different flash based solution that, as you record, streams the recorded audio to a media server (Wowza, Adobe Media Server or Red5) where it is saved in **.flv** files. The codecs used are those native to Flash Player: **Speex** or **NellyMoser's ASAO**. Because the data is streamed as it's recorded, FLVAR is well suited for longer recordings.

[**HTML Media Capture**](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/media-capture-in-mobile-browsers/) can be used as a fallback on mobile devices. It works by extending the `<input >` HTML tag with a new `capture` attribute and you can specify audio or video. When recording the native recording app on the device opens up and the recorded media is attached to the form. It's well supported by all mobile browsers with the exception of audio only recording on Safari for iOS, it only supports audio+video not audio only.

Here's the HTML Media Capture implementation/process for video on iOS. :[image]

The process is similar on Android devices for audio. HTML Media Capture is not supported on any desktop browser.

The only cross browser solution for non Flash audio recording on desktop browsers in the foreseeable future is the [MediaStream Recording standard](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/dap/raw-file/default/media-stream-capture/MediaRecorder.html).

**MediaStream Recording** is a recent proposal by the the Media Capture Task Force for a JS API who's purpose is to make audio and video recording in the browser very simple. It's currently implemented only in Firefox 27 and for audio only. [This article](http://hdfvr.com/html5-video-recording#MediaStreamRecording) covers the standard in more detail.